SELECT FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED in Postgresql is not skipping a record that should be skipped
I would like to build a queue of Articles where each article has a last_seen_at.
User arrives on web page, server ORDERs Articles by last_seen_at ASC, selects the first and returns to the browser. The server updates last_seen_at to be NOW() before returning to the browser.
In this way an Article is moved as last in the queue if it was just delivered.
For this I use FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED.
The problem is that under heavy load and concurrent request in a few milliseconds we return the same article to two different users.
The query is
SELECT * INTO rec
                FROM articles
                ORDER BY last_seen_at ASC NULLS FIRST
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

                UPDATE articles SET last_seen_at = NOW() WHERE id = rec.id;

and the way to reproduce it is by running this script. It simulates 10 different clients that are executing requests with psql. Actual servers have more, so I tried to bring the script to bash, psql and SQL.
The idea is that 10 clients will request from the table of 20 records at almost the same time and each client should receive a unique article to read. There should be no duplicates.
#!/bin/bash

# Define database variables
DB_NAME="article_db"
DB_USER="...fill here..."
DB_HOST="localhost"    # Adjust as needed
DB_PORT="5432"         # Adjust as needed

# Drop the database
echo "Dropping database: $DB_NAME"
psql -U $DB_USER -c "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $DB_NAME;" postgres

echo "Database $DB_NAME has been removed."

# Create the database
echo "Creating database: $DB_NAME"
psql -U $DB_USER -c "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;" postgres


psql -U $DB_USER -c "

    CREATE TABLE articles (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        title VARCHAR(255),
        content TEXT,
        last_seen_at TIMESTAMPTZ,
        created_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW(),
        updated_at TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT NOW()
    );

    INSERT INTO articles (title, content, last_seen_at)
        VALUES
          ('Article 1', 'This is the content of article 1.', NOW()),
          ('Article 2', 'This is the content of article 2.', NOW()),
          ('Article 3', 'This is the content of article 3.', NOW()),
          ('Article 4', 'This is the content of article 4.', NOW()),
          ('Article 5', 'This is the content of article 5.', NOW()),
          ('Article 6', 'This is the content of article 6.', NOW()),
          ('Article 7', 'This is the content of article 7.', NOW()),
          ('Article 8', 'This is the content of article 8.', NOW()),
          ('Article 9', 'This is the content of article 9.', NOW()),
          ('Article 10', 'This is the content of article 10.', NOW()),
          ('Article 11', 'This is the content of article 11.', NOW()),
          ('Article 12', 'This is the content of article 12.', NOW()),
          ('Article 13', 'This is the content of article 13.', NOW()),
          ('Article 14', 'This is the content of article 14.', NOW()),
          ('Article 15', 'This is the content of article 15.', NOW()),
          ('Article 16', 'This is the content of article 16.', NOW()),
          ('Article 17', 'This is the content of article 17.', NOW()),
          ('Article 18', 'This is the content of article 18.', NOW()),
          ('Article 19', 'This is the content of article 19.', NOW()),
          ('Article 20', 'This is the content of article 20.', NOW());

" $DB_NAME

echo "" > output.txt
echo $(psql --version) >> output.txt
for i in {0..15}; do
    echo "Run $i" >> output.txt
    x=0.01
    y=0.2
    sleep_time=$(awk -v min=$x -v max=$y 'BEGIN{srand(); print min+rand()*(max-min)}')
    sleep $sleep_time # just so that NOW() returns different values and not close to each other

    for n in {0..9}; do
        psql -U $DB_USER -c "
            DO \$\$
            DECLARE
                rec RECORD;
            BEGIN
                -- Select and lock the row
                SELECT * INTO rec
                FROM articles
                ORDER BY last_seen_at ASC NULLS FIRST
                LIMIT 1
                FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;

                UPDATE articles SET last_seen_at = NOW() WHERE id = rec.id;

                -- Return the result after commit
                RAISE NOTICE 'ID: %, Title: %, Last: %', rec.id, rec.title, rec.last_seen_at;
            END \$\$;
        " $DB_NAME 2>> output.txt &
    done
    wait
    echo "Run $i done"
done

When you run the script what happens is

psql (PostgreSQL) 12.12
Run 0
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
Run 1
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 18, Title: Article 18, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 19, Title: Article 19, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 20, Title: Article 20, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
NOTICE:  ID: 17, Title: Article 17, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.191153+03
Run 2
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.357+03
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.357631+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.360134+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.366221+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.369527+03
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.370643+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.379598+03
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.38012+03
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.380929+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.381026+03
Run 3
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.529283+03
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.531521+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.53443+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.539379+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.544098+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.545991+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.889783+03
NOTICE:  ID: 18, Title: Article 18, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.552443+03
NOTICE:  ID: 19, Title: Article 19, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.55334+03
NOTICE:  ID: 20, Title: Article 20, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.553517+03
Run 4
NOTICE:  ID: 17, Title: Article 17, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.553575+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.704585+03
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.706418+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.709828+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.711804+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.714998+03
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.720595+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.72123+03
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.721629+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.721857+03
Run 5
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.721988+03
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.871198+03
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.871329+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.878223+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.873865+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.881956+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.890476+03
NOTICE:  ID: 18, Title: Article 18, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.890876+03
NOTICE:  ID: 19, Title: Article 19, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.892448+03
NOTICE:  ID: 20, Title: Article 20, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.892666+03
Run 6
NOTICE:  ID: 17, Title: Article 17, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.045753+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.046676+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.053627+03
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.049792+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.059395+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.062333+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.064246+03
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.064377+03
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.064599+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.06874+03
Run 7
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.303647+03
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.304069+03
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.310685+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.314391+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.314454+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.315747+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.8011+03
NOTICE:  ID: 18, Title: Article 18, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.317306+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.317362+03
NOTICE:  ID: 19, Title: Article 19, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.317796+03
Run 8
NOTICE:  ID: 20, Title: Article 20, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.317888+03
NOTICE:  ID: 17, Title: Article 17, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.546232+03
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.556373+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.549424+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.559143+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.028894+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.560479+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.561629+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.563405+03
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.564448+03
Run 9
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.565825+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.566152+03
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.783754+03
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.783821+03
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.791792+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.792547+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.79418+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.169286+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.801556+03
NOTICE:  ID: 18, Title: Article 18, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.801921+03
Run 10
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.80328+03
NOTICE:  ID: 19, Title: Article 19, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.803508+03
NOTICE:  ID: 20, Title: Article 20, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.021593+03
NOTICE:  ID: 17, Title: Article 17, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.02499+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.033416+03
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.036014+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.039942+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.043892+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.044432+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.295768+03
Run 11
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.046077+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.144911+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.045291+03
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.146934+03
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.151276+03
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.157833+03
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.163592+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.167025+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.169716+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.170998+03
Run 12
NOTICE:  ID: 18, Title: Article 18, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.171116+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.275763+03
NOTICE:  ID: 19, Title: Article 19, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.282054+03
NOTICE:  ID: 20, Title: Article 20, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.289475+03
NOTICE:  ID: 17, Title: Article 17, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.292438+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.294022+03
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.2951+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.295277+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.295999+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.29623+03
Run 13
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.393965+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.395886+03
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.398183+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.404+03
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.410518+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.419476+03
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.419919+03
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.420215+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.421694+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.421805+03
Run 14
NOTICE:  ID: 18, Title: Article 18, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.522213+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.524602+03
NOTICE:  ID: 19, Title: Article 19, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.531331+03
NOTICE:  ID: 20, Title: Article 20, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.533905+03
NOTICE:  ID: 17, Title: Article 17, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.538787+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.53948+03
NOTICE:  ID: 1, Title: Article 1, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.540906+03
NOTICE:  ID: 3, Title: Article 3, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.540984+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.541091+03
NOTICE:  ID: 5, Title: Article 5, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.541513+03
Run 15
NOTICE:  ID: 8, Title: Article 8, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.642186+03
NOTICE:  ID: 6, Title: Article 6, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.645733+03
NOTICE:  ID: 7, Title: Article 7, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.6465+03
NOTICE:  ID: 10, Title: Article 10, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.654263+03
NOTICE:  ID: 12, Title: Article 12, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.659976+03
NOTICE:  ID: 13, Title: Article 13, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.661056+03
NOTICE:  ID: 9, Title: Article 9, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.661537+03
NOTICE:  ID: 11, Title: Article 11, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.662008+03
NOTICE:  ID: 14, Title: Article 14, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.663009+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.663025+03

We do 15 runs and in this 15 runs of requesting 10 articles in parallel, we get:
In run 3, article 16 was returned two times
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.545991+03
NOTICE:  ID: 16, Title: Article 16, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:55.889783+03

In run 7 article 15 was returned two times
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.315747+03
NOTICE:  ID: 15, Title: Article 15, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.8011+03

In run 8 article 4 was returned two times
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.549424+03
NOTICE:  ID: 2, Title: Article 2, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:56.559143+03
NOTICE:  ID: 4, Title: Article 4, Last: 2024-10-03 23:07:57.028894+03

and so on.
It happens about 5-10 percent of the cases.
What I fail to understand is why FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED is not working the way I would expect it to work - lock a row and if others try to lock it they should move to a different row.
Thanks

This Return the result after commit is not correct as Last: %' is pointing at rec.last_seen_at which is the value at the SELECT * INTO rec not after the UPDATE.

Another thing to keep in mind is that now() returns the transaction timestamp, which is taken when the SELECT ... FOR UPDATE executes. It can easily happen that a transaction that started earlier commits later.

@AdrianKlaver yes, the value that we print is the one that we get from the select. It is there only for debug purpose and information to help understand. It is not the value after the update, and it also makes not difference which value is printed. The id of the article is what matters.

@LaurenzAlbe it could happen, and this does not matter here. It will always put the last_seen_at at the bottom of the list

In each run you're deploying the 10 psql instances and pushing them to background, in sequence. They do not start all at once so there's a chance two immediately following workers catch the same row just because the first one commits before the second one even runs the select, so the lock's already lifted and it just happens to still be the earliest available row even after bumping up its timestamp.

You can take snapshots of your target table and pg_locks each worker sees and also collect clock_timestamp()s for more context. You can also add a pg_sleep() in there before taking the lock and another before completion to emulate something closer to true concurrency, so that workers are weighed down a bit, preventing earlier ones from finishing before the final ones even start.

In each run you're deploying the 10 psql instances and pushing them to background, in sequence:
for n in {0..9}; do
        psql -U $DB_USER -c "/*Script*/" $DB_NAME 2>> output.txt &
done

They do not start all at once so there's a chance any two following workers catch the same row, one worker after another, just because the earlier one commits before the later one even runs the select. The select..for update gets you a transaction-level lock:

Row-level locks are released at transaction end or during savepoint rollback, just like table-level locks.

That lock might be already lifted before the later worker arrives.
If at that point the row also just happens to still hold the earliest last_seen_at, even after bumping up its timestamp, the worker is forced to pick it: order by demands it, and it's no longer locked for for update skip locked to skip it.
As a result, two workers can get the same row in the same run, but that does not mean they're processing it at the same time, or that locks are somehow disregarded.
Note how the second row 16 has a mich higher timestamp than all others in its run:



id
last_seen_at




16
2024-10-03 23:07:55.545991+03


16
2024-10-03 23:07:55.889783+03


18
2024-10-03 23:07:55.552443+03


19
2024-10-03 23:07:55.55334+03


20
2024-10-03 23:07:55.553517+03



Same story with the other two "violators" - they arrived late enough to catch a row just released by an earlier, quicker commiter from that same run.
Tracking all this just based on the end result is tricky because:

You're updating the timestamp to now() which is the current time as of the start of the transaction, and

not the time of the locking select
not the time of the subsequent update
not the time you RAISE NOTICE to write this in the log
not the commit at the end, when the lock's lifted
not the script start or finish.


Even though all your workers perform the same task, it's not guaranteed how much time it'll take for any of them. The one that started first might finish last, or whenever.
Even though they are started in a specific order, they are not even guaranteed the 1st one manages to connect and cache a now() before the 10th.
Even if the 1st worker does manage to connect before the 10th worker, it might happen that the 10th connects later, gets a later now(), but beats the 1st one to running the select and locking a row.
The order in which they proceed to run their update may also be different.
The order in which they raise might be different.
The order in which the OS writes their NOTICE messages to the output.txt file might be different.
They commit and close the session at different times.

Watch it go back and forth in Run 6:



id
last_seen_at




4
2024-10-03 23:07:56.046676+03


2
2024-10-03 23:07:56.053627+03


1
2024-10-03 23:07:56.049792+03


3
2024-10-03 23:07:56.059395+03



To make sure, you can take snapshots of your whole target table and pg_locks each worker sees and also collect somewhat more current clock_timestamp()s in addition to the transaction-starting now()s for more context:

clock_timestamp() returns the actual current time, and therefore its value changes even within a single SQL command. (...) now() is a traditional PostgreSQL equivalent to transaction_timestamp()

You can also add a pg_sleep() in there before taking the lock and another before completion to emulate something closer to true concurrency, so that workers are weighed down a bit, preventing earlier ones from finishing before the final ones even start.


in sequence:

Yes they are pushed to the background in sequence, but that's enough to simulate enough of a concurrency for the example.
Even if they are pushed like this when one of them gets an article, locks it and updates it, the next one that could not acquire a lock should skip this and take a different one from the order. Why is someone taking the same one from the order.

two following workers catch the same row just because the earlier one commits before the later one even runs the select,
Why would they catch the same row? Once a row is selected it should be locked, right?


Right. It should be locked and it is locked. Then processed, then unlocked once the worker commits - those are transaction-level locks. They catch the same row but not at the same time. My point is the current method of deploying them allows for sequential execution of that script, so there's always a chance by the time worker 9 starts, some of the other 8 could've released the lock already so the exact same row is free to be reused. Again: this is not enough to reliably emulate concurrency. Add the delays and the added context and it should be easier to track.

There is a chance to be released but it will be put at the bottom of the list as the last_seen_at was updated - it will be at the end and released, so whoever is waiting should not pick it up as whoever is waiting is ordering by last_seen_at, right?

Correct, but 1) You're updating the timestamp to now() which is the current time as of the start of the transaction, not the time of the locking select, not the subsequent update, not the commit, not the script start or finish. 2) they all perform the same task, but it's not guaranteed how much time it'll take for any of them. 3) you're not even guaranteed the 1st psql manages to connect and cache a now() before the 10th. 4) Collect all this and make the script show it to you. Each of the workers can take a picture of all the last_seen_ats and pg_locks it saw when it got in.

Thank you. I have changed it to clock_timestamp(). Same result. Regarding "Even though they are started in a specific order, they are not even guaranteed the 1st one manages to connect and cache a now() before the 10th." we wait for all 10 processed to finish before executing another 10. So the first 10 should pick 10 different articles. I added pg_sleep and yes, if in the transactions we sleep and then select and update I don't see the issue, but this sleep could not be in the production system. Will check the pg_locks

I think this is valuable "If at that point the row also just happens to still hold the earliest last_seen_at, even after bumping up its timestamp, the worker is forced to pick it: order by demands it, and it's no longer locked for for update skip locked to skip it."
Why would you still hold the earliest last_seen_at. When it was selected to be updated the other processes should skip it, right? Even if the row still holds an earlier version of last_seen_at.
I am wondering if this does not work what would be the right way to implement the above and not see the issue without using.. pg_sleep().

To clarify: those recommendations were only for your test, to make it more visible what's exactly happening. You didn't show what you're really doing on production environment so I'm not addressing that - clock_timestamp() wasn't supposed to solve anything and pg_sleep() is an especially bad idea on prod. If you're trying to prevent workers from the same run to reprocess the same records, add a smallint ticker column and increment it in your final update. Then, your locking select can order by ticker, last_seen_at

Waiting for the 10 to finish before starting another run prevents nothing - reprocessing happens within that single batch of 10.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I think you are seeing a result of this (from the docs):

It is possible for a SELECT command running at the READ
COMMITTED transaction isolation level and using ORDER BY and a locking
clause to return rows out of order. This is because ORDER BY is
applied first. The command sorts the result, but might then block
trying to obtain a lock on one or more of the rows. Once the SELECT
unblocks, some of the ordering column values might have been modified,
leading to those rows appearing to be out of order

So the ordering is applied with the old value of last_seen_at, but then when it goes to lock the first row, a new value has already been committed and it sees that post-commit value but doesn't reapply the ORDER BY.  (The doc description is in terms of blocking, which doesn't literally apply here as it doesn't actually block, instead finding the commit has already happened so no blocking was necessary)

There should be no duplicates.

But clearly there should be duplicates. You are applying 160 updates to only 20 rows, there has to be duplicates. The duplicates are not happening in the order you want them to, but that isn't something you can control with the isolation level you are using.  If you had actually prevented duplicates, like by setting a seen-already-flag in your UPDATE and including that flag test in your WHERE, then the mechanism would work to prevent duplicates.
